# Adding a Launch Screen changes the display of my whole app

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, retina-display, launch-screen

I tried adding a launch screen to my app. I tried the simplest : just add a new file of type Launch screen to my project (and do nothing more). But this seems to change the resolution of my whole application. Here are sample screens of the same controller of my application with and without the Launch Screen :

without the launch screen :

[image]

with the launch screen :

[image]

Strangely, once I have used the Launch Screen once, I need to quit and re-launch the simulator to re-obtain the original resolution.

What should I do and which resolution is the correct one to work with ? Does it have something to do with retina ?
I can copy-paste the code generated in the LaunchScreen.xib if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's documentation:

> You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs
>   on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6.

By adding a launch screen you activated native support for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. That means that your app is no longer scaled up to adapt the larger screens of the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, but uses the full resolution of those larger screens (which IMHO is a good thing that you should do).